# Need assistance with my collision detection in my pong game python

Tags: python, pong, codeskulptor

NO LONGER NEED HELP

The bug I'm encountering is that when the ball spawns, collision detection won't consistently work.

This seems to happen more often when I increase the ball velocity (which is necessary). If you need any more code just ask.

```
 if ball_pos[1] > paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1]<paddle1_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT +2 and ball_pos[0] - BALL_RADIUS <= PAD_WIDTH+2:
    ball_vel[0] = -1.1*ball_vel[0]
    ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]

elif ball_pos[1] > paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1] < paddle2_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT+2 and WIDTH - (WIDTH - (ball_pos[0] + BALL_RADIUS)) >= (WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH) -2:
    ball_vel[0] = -1.1*ball_vel[0]
    ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]
```

Comment: what framework are you using for the game?

Comment: Because the problem happens more when the ball is moving faster, it's very possible that your ball movement code is "teleporting" the ball to a new position which sometimes completely skips over the paddle. Please post your code that moves the ball as well.

Comment: If you no longer need help, then place your answer below so that you can help others that find your post

Comment: it was more of the fact that i found a way to work around it

Comment: @RyanThompson then consider to remove your question or the notice NO LONGER NEED HELP.